# multiple django requirements with docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

i am new to docker and i am having issues building a new image when using Django with multiple requirements. It's failing to pip install them.

I am getting

```
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements/local.txt'
Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements/local.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1`
```

My code is :

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements/local.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements/local.txt
COPY . /code/
```

What is the proper syntax no make this work when running `docker-compose up` ?

cheers

Comment: you try to `pip install -r requirements/local.txt`, but you copy your file in `/code/requirements`, it is not correct

Comment: i changed to `RUN pip install -r /code/requirements/local.txt` but it still does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Dockerfile` you have:

```
COPY requirements/local.txt /code/
```

If you add after this...

```
RUN ls
```

...you can see:

```
Step 5 : RUN ls
 ---> Running in 88fd7cc1a616
local.txt
```

So you want:

```
RUN pip install -r local.txt
```

**Update**

There is no magic; if you want to maintain your local structure, you need to be explicit about that in your Dockerfile.  You can do this:

```
COPY requirements requirements
```

Which will copy the entire `requirements` directory into `/code`, or you can do this:

```
RUN mkdir requirements
COPY requirements/local.txt requirements/local.txt
```

Comment: if i do `COPY requirements/local.txt /code/requirements/` and then
`WORKDIR /code` shouldn't i be able to just `RUN pip install -r requirements/local.txt` ?? i really wanted to keep my original folder structure